# Attempting to compile a 32 bit application on CentOS results in error

Tags: c++, compilation

So I have installed devtools, but I am guessing that my libstdc++ library is not the correct version or is not 32 bit? I get this error when attempting to compile. How do I fix this?

```
/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/ld: skipping incompatible /opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/libstdc++_nonshared.a when searching for -lstdc++_nonshared
/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/ld: cannot find -lstdc++_nonshared
```

Comment: `x86_64-redhat-linux` it's right there, you only have the 64 bit libraries installed and it can't use them.

Comment: Is there any way to install the 32 bit libs?

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issues and have tired with devtoolset 1, 1.1 and 2, all with the same result. Looking into this further I see in the directory:

```
/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.0/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-CentOS-linux/4.7.0
```

There is a "32" directory and in here there are some library file and links to another directory that indicate "i386":

```
libitm.a -> ../../../i386-CentOS-linux/4.7.0/libitm.a
libitm.so
libquadmath.a -> ../../../i386-CentOS-linux/4.7.0/libquadmath.a
libquadmath.so
libstdc++.a -> ../../../i386-CentOS-linux/4.7.0/libstdc++.a
libstdc++_nonshared.a -> ../../../i386-CentOS-linux/4.7.0/libstdc++_nonshared.a
libstdc++.so
libsupc++.a
```

This "i386" directory is not installed using yum using a command like:

```
yum install devtoolset-2
```

on a x64 CentOS machine.

So as Zinglish above asks, how can the 32 bit libraries be installed on a 64 bit OS with yum?  I'm using http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2 for the RPM source.

Comment: Not sure if this is the best answer but it worked for me. I downloaded and installed (rpm -ivh)devtoolset-2-libquadmath-devel-4.8.2-15.el5.i386.rpm
devtoolset-2-libstdc++-devel-4.8.2-15.el5.i386.rpm manually which placed the libraries for 32 bit in the correct location so I can now compile x64 and x86 using devtools.

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue with 64 bit CentOS 6 and devtoolset 1.1.

It seems that 32 bit libraries are installed in:

> /opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/32

Some of the libraries in the directory are symlinked to files in ../../../**i686-redhat-linux**/4.7.2/, which don't exist.

So I explicitly installed devtoolset 32 bit libraries:

> yum install devtoolset-1.1.*i686

But somehow they are installed in /opt/**rh**/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.7.2/ so manually symlinked the directory to desired place:

> ln -s /opt/rh/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux /opt/rh/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/lib/gcc/.

and finally succeeded compiling 32 bit app.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue before and I guess a reason and found a solution.

**circumstance:**

```
(centos6 x64 g++)
```

**problem: When I tried to compile .cpp and .h with Makefile I got an error below..**

```
skipping incompatible .../libstdc++.so
```

**reason:**

```
> tried to compile 32bit at 64bit linux machine(centos). However there
> was no appropriate g++ library.
```

**solution:Install libstdc++**

```
yum list *stdc*
yum install libstdc++-devel.i686
```

Comment: You are talking about the standard gcc installation for centos6. The OP is talking about using a different compiler provided by devtoolset.